# How to get drawable name from imageView

Tags: java, android, random

I have an app that create a random image when the activity opens. There are like 30 images in the random image array. The image is generated, but what I want is to write the drawable name into a textview.  It looks like this:

```
    ImageView RImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    RImage.setImageResource(generator());

    Drawable myDrawable = RImage.getDrawable();

    TextView writeID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idtext);
    writeID.setText(String.valueOf(generator()));
}

private int generator() {
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.list3);
    int imgid = imgs.getResourceId(new Random().nextInt(imgs.length()), -1);
    imgs.recycle();
    return imgid;
}
```

Currently I receive numbers, and I cant figure out how can I convert the int to a string, or how can I use the generator to generate a string, display in the textview and then convert it to int to display it in the imageview.

I created an another activity where I can pick the image I want to see from a spinner, it simply send the selected option with string to the next activity on button press, and in the other activity i remove the .png and res/drawable/ from the string, and convert the string into an int to display the image.

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String transportItemChosen = extras.getString("SpinnerValue");
    transportItemChosen = transportItemChosen.replace(".png", "");
    transportItemChosen = transportItemChosen.replace("res/drawable/", "");

    String uri = ("@drawable/" + transportItemChosen);
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

   ImageView mImageView;
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedimage);
    mImageView.setImageResource(id);
```

So I need the generator to generate to string and then convert it to int. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code by converting your `int` ids into `String` names by Using the method

```
getResourceEntryName(int id);
```

**Change the line:**

```
writeID.setText(String.valueOf(generator()));
```

**To Something like:**

```
writeID.setText(getResources().getResourceEntryName(generator()));
```

**And for Viceversa:**

And if you are having a `String` lets assume this `String` you get from a textView or using above method to convert it back to an `int` id you do the following:

```
int id= getResources().getIdentifier("your_string_here", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

And if you are calling the code from a `Fragment` not an `Activity` remember to put `getActivity()` before calling `getResources()`or before calling `getPackageName()`.
I have not tested the code as I am typing, but I am sure it will work (may be a typo) for more information consider visting the Documentation on Resources [from this official link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is to take a look at [getResourceName(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName(int)%22getResource%22) method - it returns resource name by its id. Also you can use [getIdentifier(String,String,String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to retrieve resource id by its name.

If you want to display name of the randomly picked image, you should save the generated resource id into the variable and get corresponding resource name for it instead of calling `generator()` method twice as you'll get two different ids.