# How to convert image name to string after randomly selecting from folder

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm quite new to progamming. So here's my function to select a random image in my drawable folder.

```
fun generateimage(index:Int)
{var images=arrayOf(R.drawable.img1,....)
main_imageView.setImageResource(images[index])
```

This works as an image is shown randomly every time I start the application. But I would like to be able to know which image was selected. Preferably from retrieving the image name to string.

Comment: you will have to create a map of corresponding image name and their id. once you get the random index, convert the map to list of MapEntry and pick the key as image name and set the imageResource to value.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of
[How to get drawable name from imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863305/how-to-get-drawable-name-from-imageview)

However, a better implementation would be to have the value in a list of int and put your R.drawable items inside it. That was you can access which element is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
fun main() {

   val arrayImages = arrayOf("image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5") 
   // in your case actual images.
   val randomIndex = (0..arrayImages.size).random()

   val randomImage = arrayImages[randomIndex]
   println(randomImage)  // in your case: main_imageView.setImageResource(randomImage)
}
```

Note that you need to assign the variable of *randomImage* so you can access it later on. I don't know what type "*R.drawable.img1"* is, but the object you set inside this array has to store the name of the file, so you can retrieve it that way.